# How can you edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf without getting an internal server error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, raspberry-pi, debian, localhost

I am playing around with my localhost website and I made a .htaccess file to try to redirect any extension to a page called profile.php. Here's that code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

However whenever I go to an extension to the website (add /jason_bhalla for example), I get this error message:

[Not Found Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oikDU.png)

I found something that says that I should edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and change this:

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However, when I do that, I get this error message whenever I go to *any* page on localhost, even ones that are already specific pages:

[Internal Server Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZoUs.png)

Also, when I add this to apache2.conf, I get the same error message:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/social/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

So my question is, what can I do to get it to work so I can add any extension to the localhost and get it to redirect to profile.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Go check what the error log has to say, that is _always_ the first thing you need to do when you get a 500, and the cause is not immediately obvious. (Here it is probably the internal redirect limit that gets exceeded.)

Comment: @CBroe How can I find the error logs? Thanks